# R Anomaly Detection Vector (How to determine param "period")

Tags: r, vector, period

I am learning R and got some sort of stuck at the below issue:

In the anomaly detection function for vector (AnomalyDetectionVec()),
the element period  is defined as below:

"period  Defines the number of observations in a single period, and used during seasonal decomposition."

I am unable to understand how to determine the value of "period" for a series of data.

Can someone explain?

[Twitter Anomaly Detection](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series)

Answer (score 1):

period: Defines the number of observations in a single period, and used during seasonal decomposition.